# How to remove get parameter from url with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` file changes (for example) `example.com/brands/beams/...` to `example.com/php/mvc.php?htTargUrl=brands/beams/...` with `QSA` rule.

Here's the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ php/mvc.php?htTargUrl=$1 [QSA,L,B,BNP,NC]
```

And I need to remove `htTargUrl` parameter from original URL. For example:
`example.com/brands/beams/?htTargUrl=beams&par2=val` to `example.com/brands/beams/?par2=val`.

I've tried many rules to do this, but none worked with the query string.
If I use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?htTargUrl=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

then the parameter removes not only from the original link and URL becomes `example.com/php/mvc.php`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?htTargUrl=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
> ```

By itself, the rule you posted should already do what you require and remove the `htTargUrl=<something>` URL parameter from the requested URL.

However, you need to avoid removing the URL parameter from the rewritten URL - which is what appears to be happening here. You can do this with an additional condition to target direct requests only, not rewritten requests.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?htTargUrl=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

This rule also needs to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* an existing rewrites.

By checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable we ensure that only direct requests are redirected. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty on the initial request and set to "200" (as in 200 OK HTTP response code) after the first successful rewrite.

You will need to make sure that your browser cache is cleared, since any erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser. (For this reason it is advisable to first test with 302 - temporary - redirects.)